# Prononciation du nom de famille Raoult

Tags: prononciation

Ces temps-ci, on entend parler du microbiologiste **Didier Raoult**. Certains journalistes prononcent le l de son nom de famille et d’autres non.

Lorsque je parle de **Charles de Foucauld**, je ne prononce pas le l.

En français, dans quel cas le l doit-il se prononcer ? Est-ce le porteur du nom qui choisit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La prononciation des patronymes n'est pas nécessairement déterministe, chacun étant libre de prononcer son propre nom comme il le souhaite, particulièrement quand il peut s'appuyer sur une tradition familiale.

Le seul nom commun français en -oult et le mot *moult* où les deux consonnes finales sont aujourd'hui prononcées, alors que l'ancienne prononciation était la même que celle du mot *mou*.

C'est une tendance assez courante où des lettres devenues muettes sont de nouveau prononcées. Quand un nom propre garde un lien visible avec un nom commun dont l'orthographe a évolué, la prononciation s'aligne plus facilement avec ce dernier. Par exemple le nom *Prévost* est le plus souvent prononcé comme *prévôt* alors que les consonnes finales des variantes *Prost* et encore plus *Proust* sont prononcées.

Le mot *[raout](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raout)*, qui se perd, influence peut-être la prononciation où seul le *T* final s'entend, mais la prononciation actuelle la plus courante de *Raoult*, qui est aussi celle de Didier Raoult, préserve toute les consonnes même si le *L* peut parfois être atténué.

Ce n'a pas toujours été le On trouve [ici](http://raoultenvaldesaire.e-monsite.com/pages/le-saviez-vous/origine-du-nom-raoult.html) une page qui retrace l'étymologie du nom Raoult de façon très détaillée et montre que les prononciations ont pu varier avec par exemple, dans la région d'origine du nom (la Normandie) : [ro], [ra.o] ou [ra.u].

Comment: Je me demande si Raoul /raul/, où le /l/ est systématiquement prononcé, n'influence pas la prononciation de Raoult, nom qui subitement est sur toutes les lèvres.  Mais la confusion et l'incertitude sont entretenues par les noms en "ault" (Renault, Châtellerault …) où le "l" est muet.

Comment: @grandtout *Raoul*, étymologiquement apparenté à *Raoult*, joue en effet sûrement un rôle mais je ne pense pas que l’accroissement récent de la notoriété de Didier Raoult y soit pour quelque chose puisqu'il prononçait lui-même son nom comme ça il y a au moins une dizaine d'années. J'entends aussi généralement le *LT* final de feue Benoîte Groult ou du boulevard Soult, en revanche, la plupart et probablement tous les toponymes en -oult ont les deux dernières consonnes muettes. Voir par exemple Saint-Arnoult et Champs-du-Boult,